# Sorting stored Data Model Fetches in Swift Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

In Core Data it is possible to save queries as fetch requests in the data model using Xcode. There does not appear to be any way in the model to set up a sort order for the results. Worse, if you try to add a sort in code later:

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor( key: #keyPath(Venue.name), ascending: true) ]
```

the runtime will throw an error

> Can't modify a named fetch request in an immutable model.

which suggests that because the fetch was defined in the model, it is now only read only.

Does this effectively mean that if you needed a sorted result set, you cannot store the fetch request in the model?

[Please note, I am not asking how to sort fetches in general, but only if it is possible to store ***sorted*** fetches in the model or add the sort later]

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem. 
The answer lies in Apple's own [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel):

> However, once a model is being used, it must not be changed. This is enforced at runtime—when the object manager first fetches data using a model, the whole of that model becomes uneditable. Any attempt to mutate a model or any of its sub-objects after that point causes an exception to be thrown. If you need to modify a model that is in use, create a copy, modify the copy, and then discard the objects with the old model.

To sort fetch requests from Xcode, use

`func fetchRequestFromTemplate(withName name: String, substitutionVariables variables: [String : Any]) -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>?`

instead, as it returns a copy of the fetch request template.

This code of mine seemed to work (so far):

```
 guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let mom: NSManagedObjectModel = appDelegate.persistentContainer.managedObjectModel
    let filteredFetchRequest = mom.fetchRequestFromTemplate(withName: "SetsWithNotes", substitutionVariables: ["notes" : (Any).self])
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(MaxRepSet.date), ascending: false)
    filteredFetchRequest!.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    do {
        maxRepSetList = try managedContext.fetch(filteredFetchRequest!) as! [MaxRepSet]
        print(maxRepSetList.count)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: This helped me find a solution. In my case I'm calling `fetchRequestTemplate(forName:)` and setting the `sortDescriptors` property before I set up my `NSPersistentContainer`. It's worth noting that this seems to "stick"—I can call `fetchRequestTemplate(forName:)` elsewhere in my app (on the same model) and the sorting is still set. I don't think I like this approach of configuring a request in two places, but it's good to know it's possible at least.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this way :

1- store your models in core data

2- fetch data and sort them in new array by that attribute you wanted to be sort

3- create new model and save new sorted array in this model now you can store it anywhere ,

if you wanted to store it in userDefaults you need to encode and decode your models

4- remove oldest model

Good luck